# What could be causing type inference to fail in nested local scopes?

Tags: typescript

Why is type inference not working in child local scope?

```js
const obj:{ x: number | null }

// inference type
if (obj.x === null) return

// is working
obj.x    // number
{
  obj.x  //number
}

// not working
function foo() {
  obj.x // number | null
}
;(function () {
  obj.x // number | null
})()
```

```js
// why is not
function foo() {
  obj.x // number
}
;(function () {
  obj.x // number
})()
```

If the above is correct. What could be causing type inference to fail in nested local scopes?

Comment: Although `obj` is `const`, `obj.x` is not. By the time you call `foo` or other function accessing `obj.x`, `obj.x` might have been assigned another value.

Comment: You are right, solved my confusion.

Comment: So, `IIFE` can get the type inference above, async `IIFE` why not?

Comment: IIFE logically can be inline to the same scope where it belongs to, so it is guarantee to be executed before `obj.x` get a chance to be assigned new value. On the other hand async IIFE is, you guess it, async, so there is chance `obj.x` get assigned a new value before the async code is executed.

Comment: To give you an easy reasoning, imagine you await a 10 second delay before accessing `obj.x` in the async IIFE, there is plenty of time for `obj.x` to get changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, former one is influenced to `number` because of early-return. But latter one does not.

If you change your example to be early-`return`ed before usage of `foo.x`, regardless of its scope, they also influenced to be `number`. You can see it on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAED0H5QZwTwHYBcCGAPWALA9gdxqEpgKYCWAToXAA7EBQAJsQMYA2K5xoz2CMSobACMAVgC4A3qDRjQCAK4BbIcUoAfOfNatQAXzp0QoXNnIBrUggDmdAGbyEzJKV6hiaFIuqtiACgCUoBJ0oKCktqC+wiIAdBgAvIma2oGcSPLkCCGConGhoUYKyqrZRhCQ2cH5ObEYoCBFKuTZBWDl2fr6BoXYAibmljb2js6uttjYAUHZ0XEA3KVtUHS6C3S+w04uCJGBVTXzi6HLuv4B3WD9FtZ2DluuV4MAYhNT++GRswlJCimgaRkEAtQl9gfUlhVVhdjKZrjYNndRjs3tkPlFct94slWKliOlMmDQUd2qdzkA)

Comment: Thanks. But there may be a problem with my expression. It should be that the above type inference cannot be obtained in the function scope or Async IIFE.